# Set up a "relay" service

Tags: proxy, tunneling

I'm trying to create a 'left client' > server < 'right client' setup but need some advice and tips.

Let's say that I have a server-daemon on the left side, like a vnc-server that connects to the middle server.

On the right side I've got a client that want to connect to the left server-daemon, but it has to be done through the middle server. I assume this should be done with some tunneling service.

The server environment is a fully featured Debian Linux or Mac OS X Server host.

Any idéas?

Thanks / Trikks

Comment: Wow - hundreds of characters and literally zero actual information! You need to be MUCH more specific because there's nothing for us to work from here - answers range from "Impossible!" to "incredibly simple".

Comment: Alrighty, I'll try with a vnc example.

Let's say the middle-server has ip 192.168.1.2.

I need to create a socket on the server that my vnc-server on the left side can connect to. Like 'winvnc.exe -connect 192.168.1.2:5500'.

The right side should then be able to connect with a ordinary vnc-client to the middle-server, and thus connecting the left and right side.

The vnc is only an example! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried [rinetd](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Easily_forwarding_arbitrary_TCP_connections_with_rinetd)?

For arbitrary forwarding it's probably the easiest.

Comment: Nice. I did not know about it.

Answer (score 1):

SSH port forwarding? If you have to requests from `right` to the server on `left` you could do something like:

From `right`

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 middle
```

From `left`

```
ssh -R 5900:localhost:5900 middle
```

The first command sets up a tunnel, and will forward port 5900 from `right` to `middle`, and the second is a reverse tunnel, and will forward port 5900 from `middle` to `left`. These two commands should effectively provide a tunnel from `right` to `left` (I have not tested it, though)